# How would I determine the level on which item is located in binary tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

In this piece of code I am showing all File object stored in linked list. I am running this in recursive way which let me to explore the entire binary tree.

My job is to count on which level of the tree does each File object is located.

How to do this by using recursion? I was thinking of just counting variable inside, but then I don't know where to subtract the value if level goes down.

Any ideas?

```
public void display(T node)
{
    Node temp = node;

    if (temp != null)
    {
        display(temp.left);
        display(temp.right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the level at the begining of the function and decrement it at the end, just before the last line

```
private static int level = 0;    
public void displayFiles(T node)
{
    Node temp = node;

    if (temp != null && temp.leftChild != null && temp.rightChild != null)
    {
     ++level;
        displayFiles(temp.leftChild);
        displayFiles(temp.rightChild);
    }
    --level;
}
```

We will increment the level when it enters a new node and decrements it when it leaves the current node and goes to its predecessor.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework / learning problem, so here are a couple of hints.

- You don't need a counter as such.
- The neat solution involves making `displayFiles` a simple non-recursive function that uses a recursive helper function to do all of the work.  The current level is an argument for the helper function.

---

OK, so here's a sketch of a solution:

```
public void display(T node) {
    doDisplay(node, 0);
}

private void doDisplay(T node, int level) {
    if (node != null) {
        // output this node ... including the level
        display(node.left, level + 1);
        display(node.right, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Note that there is no incrementing and decrementing of a variable, so the methods are fully reentrant.

Comment: Well, I must display the entire tree and I don't know any other solution that I could display binary tree without recursion. I do have another method in fact to calculate me tabs as so levels of tree are easier visible.

Comment: I didn't say without recursion.  The recursion (and the displaying) is in the helper function.

Comment: Ah! Got you. I've visualized it bit differently.